# Nested CollectionView in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a collectionView with cell and then again a collectionView in this cell. This child collectionView is again having a cell in it. Now i want to communicate with the cell in my child collectionView from the parent collectionView. How to do that in swift 3 in storyboard? As shown in the image attached I want to communicate from first collectionView to the radio cell

[image]

Comment: you can create custom delegate/protocol methods in your parent class which child class conforms, that can be used for communication.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your main ViewController.swift conform it to the protocols UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate.
2. Now from your storyboard take an outlet of your parent CollectionView to your ViewController.swift.
3. Then create a Cocoa Touch Class which is subclass of UICollectionViewCell for your custom cell of UICollectionview and take an outlet of your child CollectionView in this class.
4. Now go to your storyboard and select your parent Collectionview cell and set its class to your custom cell class and then set an Identifier for this cell in Attributes inspector.
5. Now again create class for your child UICollectionview cell and do the same as parent UICollectionview.
6. Now everything is setup in your storyboard. After this you should write the code for your procedure in delegate methods of UICollectionView.
7. Now in your ViewController.swift file write the delegate methods of UICollectionView.

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
       {
           let cell = 
   parentCollectionViewOutlt.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "parentcell", for: indexPath) as! ParentCollectionViewCell
            cell.childCollectionView.reloadData()
           return cell
       }
8. Now in your parent CollectionView cell class file:
   Also conform it to the protocols UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate and write all delegate methods for UICollectionView and then write following code as:

   override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
         childCollectionView.delegate = self
         childCollectionView.dataSource = self
         childCollectionView.reloadData()
       }
9. Now here in cellForItemAt() method do the same procedure for taking cell of your child CollectionView by specifying its identifier and then do your code in it and return your cell. Here you can do whatever you want to do in your child CollectionView's cell that means you have an access to your child CollectionView's cell in this class for custom cell of your parent CollectionView.

Comment: Your post would be easier to read if you use [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link 
https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/
In this tutorial the same scenario is being explained just one change 
adding `UICollectionView` in `UITableViewCell`.

Go through this above link , and try to implement. It will help you